# Data binding without using spring taglib

Tags: spring, data-binding, spring-mvc, taglib

My html is built without using the spring taglib and now I'd like to bind the parameters of the form to a object in my controller.

Currently my form looks like this

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="frAccUserMgmt.userName"/>
<input type="password" name="frAccUserMgmt.userPwd"/>
</form>
```

The relevant part of my object is

```
Class FrAccUserMgmt {
    private String userName;
    private Strint userPwd;
    // getter and setter
}
```

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping("login")
Public ModelAndView doLogin(FrAccUserMgmt frAccUserMgmt) {
    //code
}
```

How do I go about binding it. Currently the binding doesn't happen. I just get an empty object in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try including the `BindingResult` class in the method signature and then see if there are any binding errors:

```
@RequestMapping("login")
Public ModelAndView doLogin(FrAccUserMgmt frAccUserMgmt, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.warn("BindingResult errors: " + result.toString());
    }
    //code
}
```

Remove the `frAccUserMgmt` part from the form field names. Spring will automatically find the command object to bind the request parameters based on the getters and setters defined in the command object.

Comment: Niether does adding the @ModelAttribute make any difference

Comment: Try adding the HttpServletRequest object to the method signature and check whether the request parameters are coming through as you expect they should. Also try renaming the inputs to just "userName" and "userPwd" (remove the frAccUserMgmt part).

Comment: The request params are coming through. If i change the method to `doLogin(String userName, String userPwd)` then they are getting bound. But I want it bound to the object directly without using the taglib since I have complex forms in the app and don't want to write controller methods with a large number of parameters or removing them one by one from the request object. Is it possible to do so without the taglibs? Thanks

Comment: taglib shouldn't make a difference to the binding once you hit the controller - as long as your HTML code is generating the same HttpServletRequest parameters, it makes no difference. I think your problem is getting your plain HTML to formulate the correct parameter names and values (as well as the correct URL, form encoding settings, etc). These probably need to be added to your `<form>` element. I do the same thing (never use Spring taglibs) and I don't have any issues binding to my form-backing bean classes. Only thing I add is `<input name="foo" value="${foo}"/>`.

Comment: Yup. Should've listened to you earlier.. :) removing the `frAccUserMgmt` part did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by adding the @ModelAttribute for the parameter bean that should be populated with the request parameters.

As per spring docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args
(16.3.3.8 Using @ModelAttribute on a method argument)

An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model. Once present in the model, the argument's fields should be populated from all request parameters that have matching names. This is known as data binding in Spring MVC, a very useful mechanism that saves you from having to parse each form field individually.